# Flutter Provider setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to load a list of events and display a loading indicator while fetching data.

I'm trying **Provider** pattern (actually refactoring an existing application).

So the event list display is conditional according to a status managed in the provider.

Problem is when I make a call to `notifyListeners()` too quickly, I get this exception :

> ════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════
>
> The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for EventProvider:
>
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
>
> ...
>
> The EventProvider sending notification was: Instance of 'EventProvider'
>
> ════════════════════════════════════════

Waiting for some milliseconds before calling `notifyListeners()` solve the problem (see commented line in the provider class below).

This is a simple example based on my code (hope not over simplified) :

**main function** :

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
    runApp(
        MultiProvider(
            providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LoginProvider()),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => EventProvider()),
            ],
            child: MyApp(),
        ),
    );
}
```

**root widget** :

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final LoginProvider _loginProvider = Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: true);
        final EventProvider _eventProvider = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context, listen: false);

        // load user events when user is logged
        if (_loginProvider.loggedUser != null) {
            _eventProvider.fetchEvents(_loginProvider.loggedUser.email);
        }

        return MaterialApp(
            home: switch (_loginProvider.status) { 
                case AuthStatus.Unauthenticated:
                    return MyLoginPage();
                case AuthStatus.Authenticated:
                    return MyHomePage();
            },
        );

    }
}
```

**home page** :

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final EventProvider _eventProvider = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context, listen: true);

        return Scaffold(
            body: _eventProvider.status == EventLoadingStatus.Loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : ListView.builder(...)
        )
    }
}
```

**event provider** :

```dart
enum EventLoadingStatus { NotLoaded, Loading, Loaded }

class EventProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

    final List<Event> _events = [];
    EventLoadingStatus _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.NotLoaded;

    EventLoadingStatus get status => _eventLoadingStatus;

    Future<void> fetchEvents(String email) async {
        //await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (){});
        _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loading;
        notifyListeners();
        List<Event> events = await EventService().getEventsByUser(email);
        _events.clear();
        _events.addAll(events);
        _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loaded;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what happens?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You are calling `fetchEvents` from within your build code for the root widget. Within `fetchEvents`, you call `notifyListeners`, which, among other things, calls `setState` on widgets that are listening to the event provider. This is a problem because you cannot call `setState` on a widget when the widget is in the middle of rebuilding.

Now at this point, you might be thinking "but the `fetchEvents` method is marked as `async` so it should be running asynchronous for later". And the answer to that is "yes and no". The way `async` works in Dart is that when you call an `async` method, Dart attempts to run as much of the code in the method as possible synchronously. In a nutshell, that means any code in your `async` method that comes before an `await` is going to get run as normal synchronous code. If we take a look at your `fetchEvents` method:

```dart
Future<void> fetchEvents(String email) async {
  //await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), (){});

  _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loading;

  notifyListeners();

  List<Event> events = await EventService().getEventsByUser(email);
  _events.clear();
  _events.addAll(events);
  _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loaded;

  notifyListeners();
}
```

We can see that the first `await` happens at the call to `EventService().getEventsByUser(email)`. There's a `notifyListeners` before that, so that is going to get called synchronously. Which means calling this method from the build method of a widget will be as though you called `notifyListeners` in the build method itself, which as I've said, is forbidden.

The reason why it works when you add the call to `Future.delayed` is because now there is an `await` at the top of the method, causing everything underneath it to run asynchronously. Once the execution gets to the part of the code that calls `notifyListeners`, Flutter is no longer in a state of rebuilding widgets, so it is safe to call that method at that point.

You could instead call `fetchEvents` from the `initState` method, but that runs into another similar issue: you also can't call `setState` before the widget has been initialized.

The solution, then, is this. Instead of notifying all the widgets listening to the event provider that it is loading, have it be loading by default when it is created. (This is fine since the first thing it does after being created is load all the events, so there shouldn't ever be a scenario where it needs to not be loading when it's first created.) This eliminates the need to mark the provider as loading at the start of the method, which in turn eliminates the need to call `notifyListeners` there:

```dart
EventLoadingStatus _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loading;

// or

late EventLoadingStatus _eventLoadingStatus;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loading;
}

...

Future<void> fetchEvents(String email) async {
  List<Event> events = await EventService().getEventsByUser(email);
  _events.clear();
  _events.addAll(events);
  _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loaded;

  notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: To be honest I thought there was some internal processing that would prevent `NotifyListeners()` to call `setState()` while widget is building (except from being called manually). As I have only stateless widgets in my whole app, and do not call any `setState()`, I did not understand. My first though was to fetch events in the `EventProvider` constructor, but I need the user email from the `LoginProvider` and have not managed to get it to work even passing constructor argument on routing (gave me exception `(inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ModalScopeStatus) or inheritFromElement() was called`.

Comment: This is why I ended calling `fetchEvents` in my root widget. However I just see that [ProxyProvider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#proxyprovider) could help in this case, I have to give it a try. But for that specific case I could just assume it is loading by default when it is created as you and Benjamin suggested. Anyway that is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, this is much more clear now, thanks!

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem and this solution worked for me but I'm mystified why, specifically about the comment "so it should be running asynchronous for later." I haven't done much async programming, but can't async function run anytime? In other words, couldn't the build thread swap out in the middle of a build and the async notifyListeners get called, resulting in the same error?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys Asynchronous programming shouldn't be confused with multi-threaded programming. `async` just means the method can be finished later, not that it will be finished on a different thread. Dart is purely a single-threaded language, so your situation can't happen. What would happen is that when the thread has downtime (between drawing frames, for instance), it checks the async queue to see if any futures have completed. If they have, the results of those futures are returned and any code that was `await`ing them is resumed. There's 0% chance of this happening in the middle of a build.

Comment: its only run once , when i click button to re fetch , the eventState doesnt watch or change ... alr put to set loading ...

Comment: so i need 1 void again to set only loading to true with notifylistener , 

```
// gestureDetector
context.read<ModelBrain>().eventLoading();  // need added this one , if i didnt put like these , the state doesnt change...
context.read<ModelBrain>().getData();
```

```
initFetch(){
context.read<ModelBrain>().getData(); //
}
``` 
and now i fix ```setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build```

Comment: still not solve , i have listen from consumer then in consumer i need set marked loading = true . because have an event that trigger need to re fetch data.

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo I suggest posting your problem in a new question so you can share your code in a more readable and sharable format. You aren't likely to get good answers by cramming everything into the comment section of a three-year-old answer.

Comment: @Abion47 ya alr created a new question, and alr solved .

Answer (score 8):

The issue is you calling `notifyListeners` twice in one function. I get it, you want to change the state. However, it should *not* be the responsibility of the EventProvider to notify the app when it's loading. All you have to do is if it's not loaded, assume that it's loading and just put a `CircularProgressIndicator`. Don't call `notifyListeners` twice in the same function, it doesn't do you any good.

If you really want to do it, try this:

```
Future<void> fetchEvents(String email) async {
    markAsLoading();
    List<Event> events = await EventService().getEventsByUser(email);
    _events.clear();
    _events.addAll(events);
    _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loaded;
    notifyListeners();
}

void markAsLoading() {
    _eventLoadingStatus = EventLoadingStatus.Loading;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: Calling `notifyListeners` twice in one method is usually redundant (though not always), but there's no real adverse effect in doing it. This is not the cause of OP's error.

Comment: Abion47 is right, I have other methods that call `notifyListeners()` twice without any problem. And in this case if I add a wait before first notify, then I can call `notifyListeners()` multiple times without any problem. But the finality of your answer is right, I could have simply assumed it's loading by default.

Comment: does calling notifyListeners() inside markAsLoading method change anything? Looks the same to me.

Comment: @funder7 No, it doesn't change anything. Moving the second call to `notifyListeners` to within another function doesn't change the fact that both calls are happening within the scope of `fetchEvents`. Though like I said before, calling `notifyListeners` twice in quick succession like this, while often redundant, is relatively harmless on its own.

Comment: Ok, I ready your answer more carefully, and I think you're right. Delegating UI logic to a Provider doesn't look like a good idea. It would be nice to read some practical examples on how to integrate a Provider for such goals. Anything to suggest? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are calling Apis from within your code for the root widget. Within Apis, you call notifyListeners, which, among other things, calls setState on widgets that are listening to the event provider. So firstly remove setState in your code and make sure Future use when call apis in init state

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.microtask(() => context.read<SellCarProvider>().getBrandService(context));
  }
```